# Returning type error on login laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting an error of:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController::authenticated() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php on line 115
```

Here is my custom `authenticated()`

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user){
    $successmessage = 'Welcome back, '.Auth::user()->username.'!';
    $request->session()->flash('success', $successmessage);
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

which returns that error above. any help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to user Request from `\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request`
Change you method declaration like below:

```
protected function authenticated(\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request $request, $user){
                                ^^ //here is a change
    $successmessage = 'Welcome back, '.Auth::user()->username.'!';
    $request->session()->flash('success', $successmessage);
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
use App\Http\Requests;
```

To

```
use Request;
```

Comment: Still doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the class Request exist in App\Http\Controllers\Auth folder.
If exist just include the Request path after the namespace:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this..

```
use Auth;
use Request;

protected function authenticated($user){ //Changed

    $successmessage = 'Welcome back, '.Auth::user()->username.'!';

    Request::session()->flash('success', $successmessage); //Changed

    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());

}
```

I hope this will work.